# current_url() returns false URLs like the favicon address in the page header in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to record the page details which the user is visiting and store them in the database. So, I wrote a function in a helper named `hits_helper.php` which uses the `current_url()` of codeigniter to do it.

```
function count_hits($options = array())
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $CI->load->library('user_agent');

    $date = date('Y-m-j H:i:s', strtotime(date('Y-m-j H:i:s')) + 1214);

    $data = array (

        'page_Address'  =>   current_url(),

        'hit_Date'      =>   $date

    );

    $CI->db->insert('counter', $data);

}
```

**url helper is autoloaded.**

**It works and inserts the page url in the database**, but it also inserts some urls like the favicon.ico and some css urls in the head section of the page respectively. What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Try with load url library `$CI->load->helper('url');`

Comment: Load `url` helper as you are calling `current_url` which is in url helper

Comment: As I said, it inserts the page url and it works. This means that url helper is autoloaded. But, it also inserts some false urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new helper name My_url_helper

```
function current_url()
{
$CI =& get_instance();

$url = $CI->config->site_url($CI->uri->uri_string());
return $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ? $url.'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : $url;
}
```

May be it help you

Comment: I am going to test it for two days and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong, and your model function does what it is suppose to do. Using this approach, you could create a filter function, to exclude exceptions, like this:

```
function filter_hits(){
    $exeptions = array('css', 'js', 'images');
    foreach($exceptions as $exception){
       if(!strpos(current_url(), 'http://'. base_url() . $exception))
           $this->count_hits(current_url());
    }
}
```

, where `count_hits()` would take `current_url()` string as parameter.

```
function count_hits($current_url, $options = array())
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $CI->load->library('user_agent');

    $date = date('Y-m-j H:i:s', strtotime(date('Y-m-j H:i:s')) + 1214);

    $data = array (

        'page_Address'  =>   $current_url,

        'hit_Date'      =>   $date

    );

    $CI->db->insert('counter', $data);

}
```